# How do I make a query that returns all nodes reachable a given node?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb

How do I make a query that returns all nodes reachable from a given node along with their distances from there? I'm using Memgraph graph database.

I've tried using

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

But it is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Memgraph for an unweighted graph, where the distance is counting hops between nodes, you can use the BFS algorithm:

```
MATCH path=(n:City {name: 'Berlin'})-[:Road *bfs]->(m)
RETURN m, size(relationships(path));
```

If you have a weighted graph, use weighted shortest algorithm to calculate the total weight to another node:

```
MATCH (n:City {name: 'Oulu'})-[:Road *WSHORTEST(r, n | r.length) total_weight]->(m)
RETURN m, total_weight;
```

To learn more about the syntax and use of these algorithms, head to:
https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/built-in-graph-algorithms