# Memgraph query failed trying to find all connected paths to a specific node

Tags: memgraphdb

When trying to find and return all the paths connected to a specific node:

```
MATCH p = (DocID:ProjectList {DocumentID: "specificied_doc"})-[*]-(*)
RETURN p
```

Memgraph lab looses connection with a `Query Failed, [object ProgressEvent]` error.

I am expecting about 41 paths to be shown with some depth and some without any depth.

Trying to use:

```
MATCH p = (DocID:ProjectList {DocumentID: "specificied_doc"})-[*]-(n)
RETURN p
```

Yields the same error without any results.

I am running memgraph in a docker desktop container, increasing the number of allocated cpus via wslconfig does not make any difference.

Comment: Running the following query displays all results without any problem: `MATCH links = (Projectlist)-[:references]->(Reflist) RETURN links`

Answer (score 3):

The following link pointed me in the right direction:
[How do I make a query that returns all nodes reachable a given node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74235243/how-do-i-make-a-query-that-returns-all-nodes-reachable-a-given-node?rq=2)

Seems that using bfs works and prevents the memgraph lab error and query failure:

```
MATCH p = (DocID:ProjectList {DocumentID: "specificied_doc"})-[:references *bfs]->(n) RETURN p
```

Comment: I am glad you found a solution because I wanted to comment that when I try running your first example, it fails on query syntax. I get this error: `Query failed: line 1:68 extraneous input '*' expecting {AFTER, ALTER, ANALYZE, ASYNC, AUTH .....`. I think the Lab error has to do with some timeout happening between Lab <> Memgraph.